# numpy.random.shuffle returns None

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I installed `numpy1.8.2` and then I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
print a, np.random.shuffle(a)
```

but its output is :

`[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] None`

I don't know why it returns `None`, according to its [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#numpy.random.shuffle) it should be worked! I can't figure out the problem.

I'm using `PyCharm 3.1` on Windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`shuffle` works in place and therefore does not return a value.

```
In [1]: x = range(9)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [5]: print numpy.random.shuffle(x)
None

In [6]: x
Out[6]: [8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to 'shuffle' out of place then use [`np.random.permutation`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html?highlight=random%20permutation#numpy.random.permutation).

e.g.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.permutation([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[2]: array([3, 5, 1, 4, 2])
```

Comment: The only post that answers the actual underlying question

Answer (score 2):

Sir, it must output that way. **`.shuffle()`** returns **`None`**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.random.shuffle.__doc__

    shuffle(x)

        Modify a sequence in-place by shuffling its contents.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : array_like
            The array or list to be shuffled.

        Returns
        -------
        None

        Examples
        --------
        >>> arr = np.arange(10)
        >>> np.random.shuffle(arr)
        >>> arr
        [1 7 5 2 9 4 3 6 0 8]

        This function only shuffles the array along the first index of a
        multi-dimensional array:

        >>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
        >>> np.random.shuffle(arr)
        >>> arr
        array([[3, 4, 5],
               [6, 7, 8],
               [0, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.shuffle` doesn't return anything but rather shuffles the array in place.
Try the following instead

```
print np.random.shuffle(a), a
```

You'll see that your array was indeed shuffled as you applied the function to the array before printing it.